# knitr to produce pdf output file

Tags: r, knitr

I would like to be able to use `knitr` to produce a structured PDF file. I did not see anything unless the input file is `Sweave` format. This question may be too vague but I really like to know right from `knitr`, is it possible to create a structured PDF output file without using any `Sweave` or `LaTeX`?

Comment: Everybody loves being greedy (spend less, get more), but this kind of questions are often hard to answer. If such a perfect approach exists, LaTeX should be dying now. Anyway, take a look at R Markdown and Pandoc, and at the end of the day, you will come back to LaTeX; you just cannot kill the beast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using command knit2pdf if you haven't already.

Comment: note deleted answer (which should have been a comment): "The knit2pdf answer does not work (as I experienced myself) because knit2pdf uses texi2pdf to call pdflatex and therefore requires latex (and not markdown as the OP seems to imply) as input."